# Which signature is most effective when using multiple conditions or Results? How to bubble errors correctly?

Tags: rust, error-handling, traits

**Introduction**

I'm learning rust and have been trying to find the right signature for using multiple Results in a single function and then returning either correct value, or exit the program with a message.

So far I have 2 different methods and I'm trying to combine them.

**Context**

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```rust
fn blur(image: DynamicImage, amount: &str) -> DynamicImage {
    let amount = parse_between_or_error_out("blur", amount, 0.0, 10.0);
    image.brighten(amount)
}
```

This is what I have working now, but would like to refactor.

```rust
fn blur(image: DynamicImage, amount: &str) -> DynamicImage {
    match parse::<f32>(amount) {
        Ok(amount) => {
            verify_that_value_is_between("blur", amount, 0.0, 10.0);
            image.blur(amount)
        }
        _ => {
            println!("Error");
            process::exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

**Combining these methods**

Now here's the two working methods that I'm trying to combine, to achieve this.

```rust
fn parse<T: FromStr>(value: &str) -> Result<T, <T as FromStr>::Err> {
    value.parse::<T>()
}
```

```rust
fn verify_that_value_is_between<T: PartialOrd + std::fmt::Display>(
    name: &str,
    amount: T,
    minimum: T,
    maximum: T,
) {
    if amount > maximum || amount < minimum {
        println!(
            "Error: Expected {} amount to be between {} and {}",
            name, minimum, maximum
        );
        process::exit(1)
    };

    println!("- Using {} of {:.1}/{}", name, amount, maximum);
}
```

**Here's what I tried**

I have tried the following. I realise I'm likely doing a range of things wrong. This is because I'm still learning Rust, and I'd like any feedback that helps me learn how to improve.

```rust
fn parse_between_or_error_out<T: PartialOrd + FromStr + std::fmt::Display>(
    name: &str,
    amount: &str,
    minimum: T,
    maximum: T,
) -> Result<T, <T as FromStr>::Err> {
    fn error_and_exit() {
        println!(
            "Error: Expected {} amount to be between {} and {}",
            name, minimum, maximum
        );
        process::exit(1);
    }

    match amount.parse::<T>() {
        Ok(amount) => {
            if amount > maximum || amount < minimum {
                error_and_exit();
            };

            println!("- Using {} of {:.1}/{}", name, amount, maximum);

            amount
        }
        _ => {
            error_and_exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently this looks quite messy, probably I'm using too many or the wrong types and the error needs to be in two places (hence the inlined function, which I know is not good practice).

[Full reproducible example](https://github.com/webbertakken/learning-rust/blob/main/image-processing/src/main.rs).

**The question**

How to best combine logic that is using a Result and another condition (or Result), exit with a message or give `T` as a result?

Comments on any of the mistakes are making are very welcome too.

Comment: A full answer would be long and is probably already there somewhere, so the question will probably be duplicated to some not very obvious other one. What I would like to point out: 1) If you care for code scalability, don's panic on all errors, return them in your `Result`s; 2) `?` and `impl From<XXXError> for MyError` are your friends. [Here is an article on error handling](https://dev.to/seanchen1991/a-beginner-s-guide-to-handling-errors-in-rust-40k2) that mentions it all.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched SO, and wasn't able to find any answer that goes into what signature is most effective to use in cases like this. I'd be happy with a short answer that shows a cleaner signature that can be used as an example as well. I believe this may be helpful for others too when learning rust, as it's not entirely straight forward at first.

Comment: There is no valid reason to use `&str` for`amount` - just use the proper type. This is a code smell named "primitive obsession".

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Do you mean replacing it with String? If you mean i32 or f32 then could you elaborate how you would deduplicate parsing the string that comes as cli argument to i32 or f32 respectively? I found a macro in clap (the cli args parser) [value_t](https://docs.rs/clap/2.20.0/clap/macro.value_t.html#examples) but it has a Result signature, and that's what I'm trying to combine in 1 method. Just trying to learn the right way here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a crate such as [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/) to bubble your events up and handle them as needed.

Alternatively, you can write your own trait and implement it on `Result`.

```rust
trait PrintAndExit<T> {
  fn or_print_and_exit(&self) -> T;
}
```

Then use it by calling the method on any type that implements it:

```rust
fn try_get_value() -> Result<bool, MyError> {
  MyError { msg: "Something went wrong".to_string() }
}

let some_result: Result<bool, MyError> = try_get_value();
let value: bool = some_result.or_print_and_exit();
// Exits with message: "Error: Something went wrong"
```

Implementing this trait on `Result` could be done with:

```rust
struct MyError {
    msg: String,
}

impl<T> PrintAndExit<T> for Result<T, MyError> {
    fn or_print_and_exit(&self) -> T {
        match self {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e.msg);
                std::process::exit(1);
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, and I forgot everything I learned about rust traits when I was trying to solve it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few DRY tricks.

**tl;dr**:

1. Convert other Errors into your unified error type(s) with `impl From<ExxError> for MyError`;
2. In any function that may result in an Error, use `?` as much as you can. Return `Result<???, MyError>` (*). `?` will utilize the implicit conversion.

(*) Only if MyError is an appropriate type for the function. Always create or use the most appropriate error types. (Kinda obvious, but people often treat error types as a second-class code, pun intended)

Recommendations are in the comments.

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::str::FromStr;

// Debug and Display are required by "impl Error" below.
#[derive(Debug)]
enum ProcessingError {
    NumberFormat{ message: String },
    NumberRange{ message: String },
    ProcessingError{ message: String },
}

// Display will be used when the error is printed.
// No need to litter the business logic with error 
// formatting code.
impl Display for ProcessingError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            ProcessingError::NumberFormat { message } =>
                write!(f, "Number format error: {}", message),
            ProcessingError::NumberRange { message } =>
                write!(f, "Number range error: {}", message),
            ProcessingError::ProcessingError { message } =>
                write!(f, "Image processing error: {}", message),
        }
    }
}

impl Error for ProcessingError {}

// FromStr::Err will be implicitly converted into ProcessingError,
// when ProcessingError is needed. I guess this is what
// anyhow::Error does under the hood.
// Implement From<X> for ProcessingError for every X error type
// that your functions like process_image() may encounter.
impl From<FromStr::Err> for ProcessingError {
    fn from(e: FromStr::Err) -> ProcessingError {
        ProcessingError::NumberFormat { message: format!("{}", e) }
    }
}

pub fn try_parse<T: FromStr>(value: &str) -> Result<T, ProcessingError> {
    // Note ?. It will implicitly return 
    // Err(ProcessingError created from FromStr::Err)
    Ok (
        value.parse::<T>()?
    )
}

// Now, we can have each function only report/handle errors that 
// are relevant to it. ? magically eliminates meaningless code like
// match x { ..., Err(e) => Err(e) }.
pub fn parse_between<T>(value: &str, min_amount: T, max_amount: T)
    -> Result<T, ProcessingError>
    where
        T: FromStr + PartialOrd + std::fmt::Display,
{
    let amount = try_parse::<T>(value)?;
    if amount > max_amount || amount < min_amount {
        Err(ProcessingError::NumberRange {
            message: format!(
                "Expected value to be between {} and {} but received {}",
                min_amount,
                max_amount,
                amount)
        })
    } else {
        Ok(amount)
    }
}
```

main.rs

```
use image::{DynamicImage};
use std::fmt::{Debug, Formatter, Display};

fn blur(image: DynamicImage, value: &str)
    -> Result<DynamicImage, ProcessingError> 
{
    let min_amount = 0.0;
    let max_amount = 10.0;

    // Again, note ? in the end.
    let amount = parse_between(value, min_amount, max_amount)?;
    image.blur(amount)
}

// All processing extracted into a function, whose Error
// then can be handled by main().
fn process_image(image: DynamicImage, value: &str)
    -> Result<DynamicImage, ProcessingError>
{
    println!("applying blur {:.1}/{:.1}...", amount, max_amount);
    image = blur(image, value);
    // save image ...

    image
}

fn main() {
    let mut image = DynamicImage::new(...);

    image = match process_image(image, "1") {
        Ok(image) => image,
        // No need to reuse print-and-exit functionality. I doubt
        // you want to reuse it a lot.
        // If you do, and then change your mind, you will have to
        // root it out of all corners of your code. Better return a
        // Result and let the caller decide what to do with errors.
        // Here's a single point to process errors and exit() or do
        // something else.
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error processing image: {:?}", e);
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is yet another step in complexity and slightly more challenging as a beginner, it does indeed seem to make the code more manageable. Having digested the concepts of the other answers this is a great next step. Thank you very much for the additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing my results**

I'll share my results/answer as well for other people who are new to Rust. This answer is based on that of @Acidic9's answer.

- The types seem to be fine
- [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.43/anyhow/) looks to be the de facto standard in Rust.
- I should have used a trait and implement that trait for the Error type.

I believe the below example is close to what it might look like in the wild.

```rust
// main.rs

use image::{DynamicImage};
use app::{parse_between, PrintAndExit};

fn main() {
  // mut image = ...

  image = blur(image, "1")

  // save image
}

fn blur(image: DynamicImage, value: &str) -> DynamicImage {
    let min_amount = 0.0;
    let max_amount = 10.0;

    match parse_between(value, min_amount, max_amount).context("Input error") {
        Ok(amount) => {
            println!("applying blur {:.1}/{:.1}...", amount, max_amount);
            image.blur(amount)
        }
        Err(error) => error.print_and_exit(),
    }
}
```

And the implementation inside the apps library, using anyhow.

```rust
// lib.rs

use anyhow::{anyhow, Error, Result};
use std::str::FromStr;

pub trait Exit {
    fn print_and_exit(self) -> !;
}

impl Exit for Error {
    fn print_and_exit(self) -> ! {
        eprintln!("{:#}", self);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}

pub fn try_parse<T: FromStr>(value: &str) -> Result<T, Error> {
    match value.parse::<T>() {
        Ok(value) => Ok(value),
        Err(_) => Err(anyhow!("\"{}\" is not a valid value.", value)),
    }
}

pub fn parse_between<T>(value: &str, min_amount: T, max_amount: T) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    T: FromStr + PartialOrd + std::fmt::Display,
{
    match try_parse::<T>(value) {
        Ok(amount) => {
            if amount > max_amount || amount < min_amount {
                return Err(anyhow!(
                    "Expected value to be between {} and {} but received {}",
                    min_amount,
                    max_amount,
                    amount
                ));
            };

            Ok(amount)
        }
        Err(error) => Err(error),
    }
}
```

Hopefully seeing this full implementation will help someone out there.

[Source code](https://github.com/webbertakken/learning-rust/tree/main/image-processing).